# Replacing GeoLite2 python reader with cache or database solution

Tags: python, django, maxmind

I'm trying to use maxminddb GeoLite2 in my django app so I can track the country of each request without calling an external API. However I have concerns reading how scalable the following solution is that they propose:

```
reader = maxminddb.open_database('GeoLite2-Country.mmdb')
try:
    country_object = reader.get(ip)
    country=country_object['country']['names']['en']
except: 
    country=None                        
reader.close()
```

In the module (https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-python) they mention it using a memory map but I think the above code just uses the memory map for one request only.
This means for every request there is the opening and closing of the mmdb file. Is there a way to have this file loaded into memory and every request accesses it from there rather than the file?

Comment: Are you asking how to share the reader object between requests? On the page you link, I just see a sample code demonstrating how to use the database from a script. I don't see a recommendation to open it every request when used in a web app.

Comment: Yes sorry I should have been more specific, I am looking for how to share the reader between requests without re-opening the database file each time in django. Sorry if this is extremely basic!

Comment: If you are using Nginx in front of Django, use the geoIP Nginx module rather than doing it inside Django.